# **Time Series Regression on mutual fund returns in R**

Tags: r, time-series, regression

We want to do the time series regression on the following variables:

1. rjt1 - Rf(1m)
2. InDeltaOSEBX - Rf(1m)

We have returns on well over 100 mutual funds from the mid 80's and up to today. We want to do a time series regression of the data identifying an alpha. As the data set is too big to share I have taken the first 50 lines from det data frame and printed in below (df is called TEST).

Does anyone have any tips on how to go forwards in doing this?

*(On a side note: We have tried to import the datasets with the command read.zoo producing this error message: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 3 elements
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read(file, ...) : line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read(file, ...) : line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read(file, ...) : line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls

If this have an effect on doing the time series regression we would love som feedback on solving this as well)*

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(11075, 11108, 11138, 11169, 
11200, 11229, 11261, 11291, 11320, 11353, 11381, 11411, 11442, 
11473, 11502, 11534, 11565, 11593, 11625, 11626, 11656, 11684, 
11718, 11746, 11773, 11807, 11838, 11866, 11899, 11929, 11960, 
11991, 12020, 12051, 12083, 12111, 12142, 12172, 12202, 12233, 
12264, 12293, 12325, 12356, 12384, 12416, 12447, 12475, 12508, 
12538), class = "Date"), SecurityId = c(45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731), FundId = c(109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109), Symbol = c("AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2"), 
    ISIN = c("NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576"), Name = c("ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++"), NAV = c(96.9792, 102.1109, 105.2352, 110.6285, 
    120.5222, 117.2032, 115.133, 104.2482, 102.1704, 103.0578, 
    103.8683, 94.8068, 100.8107, 102.9584, 98.032, 96.01, 90.43, 
    77.27, 78.62, 78.62, 83.27, 86.17, 85.497, 87.3472, 93.9374, 
    88.8757, 86.9814, 79.075, 74.3745, 71.6498, 60.0066, 64.1799, 
    70.2522, 62.9072, 60.6429, 56.8225, 57.1645, 64.3922, 67.9668, 
    72.9443, 79.293, 84.1295, 78.0903, 88.6589, 89.6975, 94.9707, 
    103.4249, 112.0345, 106.0645, 102.2011), NAV2 = c(102.1109, 
    105.2352, 110.6285, 120.5222, 117.2032, 115.133, 104.2482, 
    102.1704, 103.0578, 103.8683, 94.8068, 100.8107, 102.9584, 
    98.032, 96.01, 90.43, 77.27, 78.62, 78.62, 83.27, 86.17, 
    85.497, 87.3472, 93.9374, 88.8757, 86.9814, 79.075, 74.3745, 
    71.6498, 60.0066, 64.1799, 70.2522, 62.9072, 60.6429, 56.8225, 
    57.1645, 64.3922, 67.9668, 72.9443, 79.293, 84.1295, 78.0903, 
    88.6589, 89.6975, 94.9707, 103.4249, 112.0345, 106.0645, 
    102.2011, 103.5399), NAV3 = c(5.1317, 3.12430000000001, 5.3933, 
    9.8937, -3.319, -2.0702, -10.8848, -2.0778, 0.8874, 0.810500000000005, 
    -9.06150000000001, 6.0039, 2.1477, -4.9264, -2.02199999999999, 
    -5.58, -13.16, 1.35000000000001, 0, 4.64999999999999, 2.90000000000001, 
    -0.673000000000002, 1.8502, 6.5902, -5.0617, -1.8943, -7.90639999999999, 
    -4.70050000000001, -2.7247, -11.6432, 4.1733, 6.0723, -7.345, 
    -2.26430000000001, -3.8204, 0.341999999999999, 7.22770000000001, 
    3.5746, 4.97749999999999, 6.34870000000001, 4.83649999999999, 
    -6.03919999999999, 10.5686, 1.0386, 5.27319999999999, 8.4542, 
    8.6096, -5.97, -3.8634, 1.33880000000001), rjt1 = c(0.0529154705338876, 
    0.0305971252824136, 0.0512499619899045, 0.0894317467921918, 
    -0.0275384949826671, -0.0176633402500956, -0.0945410959499014, 
    -0.0199312793889966, 0.00868549012238378, 0.00786451874579124, 
    -0.0872402840905263, 0.0633277359851825, 0.0213042861521644, 
    -0.0478484514133864, -0.0206259180675697, -0.0581189459431309, 
    -0.145526926904788, 0.0174712048660542, 0, 0.0591452556601373, 
    0.0348264681157681, -0.00781014274109321, 0.021640525398552, 
    0.0754483257620164, -0.0538837566294149, -0.0213140374703097, 
    -0.0908975941982998, -0.0594435662345875, -0.0366348681335673, 
    -0.162501500353106, 0.069547349791523, 0.0946137342065039, 
    -0.104551885919587, -0.0359942900017805, -0.0629983064794065, 
    0.00601874257556424, 0.126436862038503, 0.0555129347964506, 
    0.0732342849744286, 0.0870349019731495, 0.0609952959277614, 
    -0.0717845702161548, 0.135338191811275, 0.0117145599595754, 
    0.0587887064856879, 0.0890190342916289, 0.0832449439158269, 
    -0.0532871570810777, -0.0364250055390823, 0.0130996633108646
    ), NAVAdj = c(95.1845744125828, 100.221310955192, 103.287794962456, 
    108.581290528303, 118.2919050092, 115.034323976614, 113.002433571775, 
    102.319059656894, 100.279709892053, 103.0578, 103.8683, 94.8068, 
    100.8107, 102.9584, 98.032, 96.01, 90.43, 77.27, 78.62, 78.62, 
    83.27, 86.17, 85.497, 87.3472, 93.9374, 88.8757, 86.9814, 
    79.075, 74.3745, 71.6498, 60.0066, 64.1799, 70.2522, 62.9072, 
    60.6429, 56.8225, 57.1645, 64.3922, 67.9668, 72.9443, 79.293, 
    84.1295, 78.0903, 88.6589, 89.6975, 94.9707, 103.4249, 112.0345, 
    106.0645, 102.2011), Dividends = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), CorpAdj = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), DividendAdj = c(0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lnDeltaNAV = c(0.0274417964293168, 
    -0.00350766756849463, 0.00998840819124958, 0.000928763378170494, 
    0.00791108635966342, 0.00864194816233166, 0.0144252428438243, 
    -0.0326130578043271, -0.000906896436772442, 0.0126041093498408, 
    -0.00361822884525953, 0.0137502969599446, 0.00861446066174043, 
    0.00181597289005087, 0.00621623692463391, 0.00187656435386163, 
    -0.00749149697337792, 0.0181526368786793, -0.00722390822860675, 
    0, 0.0120818190668892, 0.00651999049728147, 0.00636429145621165, 
    -0.00450742957110783, 0.007965648824654, 0.00144350537836235, 
    0.00449610891723751, 0.0141470222220663, 0.0160980643167319, 
    0.00923443722576689, -0.0174515619285609, 0.0184013947690973, 
    0.0168046574519067, -0.00552145578478402, 0.00526092497346831, 
    0.0249322910975858, -0.00910223547118605, -0.0030717369529274, 
    0.00436310066319034, -0.0101492557568088, 0.00870181996162334, 
    0.00853512319797645, -0.0131162685292976, 0.00180968961233052, 
    -0.000929359811573605, -0.00146569351793957, 0.00399055160518813, 
    0.0116587725257133, 0.0118800845637939, -0.00930675043732698
    ), lnDeltaOSEBX = c(0.0261622502400947, -0.00321159549991012, 
    0.00877033643413938, -0.00298091132522149, 0.0093168319222956, 
    0.00320695110539315, 0.0165507812371484, -0.0298292017516539, 
    -0.00279652124476559, 0.0128843812454127, -0.00303229783678471, 
    0.013455173619171, 0.00844688176370578, 0.000198668918900857, 
    0.00878666740983025, 0.00149620632806879, -0.00542067956352454, 
    0.0164522493491743, -0.00743251148673707, 0.0015308332717634, 
    0.00688373048850099, 0.00636065750845738, 0.00791876701747452, 
    -0.00349924942280122, 0.00813080992677406, 0.00511540142367028, 
    0.000964785410099367, 0.00520043045522645, 0.0146031063223155, 
    0.0120183633609647, -0.0180072054930731, 0.0162186590242435, 
    0.0168797256037649, -0.00950249030098504, 0.00365230500953562, 
    0.0221866534871467, -0.0125138949724395, -0.00085019559618793, 
    0.00396970384108641, -0.00986918851126362, 0.0101242708762337, 
    0.00582882341227275, -0.0120011170711791, 0.00305863406128282, 
    -0.00126729393020675, -0.00102163828770063, 0.00111638801472491, 
    0.0125382559692175, 0.012051247355787, -0.00862553863431081
    ), lnDeltaOBX = c(0.0222017092722471, -0.0035685318306351, 
    0.00927676647155717, -0.00322304642514126, 0.0122551306827603, 
    0.00386787017854395, 0.0194385117533802, -0.0349171093011842, 
    -0.00278043845655773, 0.0139050884791985, -0.00414777441337044, 
    0.0142337087252509, 0.0057961116712848, 0.000651260999012138, 
    0.00971445011483674, -0.000169194513667925, -0.00341789790426716, 
    0.0164112903997351, -0.00431485533650289, 0.00159580908248547, 
    0.00785272123002656, 0.00690128271707913, 0.00951926939242664, 
    -0.0043473603954407, 0.00818085801734103, 0.0063764434870901, 
    0.000407697331152867, 0.00793118483108124, 0.0150475541343758, 
    0.0128103004688169, -0.020196700812475, 0.017542971445617, 
    0.0179025661212791, -0.0113010728926346, 0.00432265578068325, 
    0.022434417862141, -0.0134021747347655, -0.00119436954337626, 
    0.00357711390482063, -0.00939315654505801, 0.0097484878707963, 
    0.00633488935549487, -0.011368112232053, 0.00311730494447282, 
    -0.00177851354914704, -0.0011414403065606, 0.00131284335288306, 
    0.0134264862303022, 0.0122844071888668, -0.00834517033849469
    ), lnDeltaOSEFX = c(0.0257512997592757, -0.00372148073099599, 
    0.00863973580821575, -0.00106204557498124, 0.0106894615262938, 
    0.0043754864256611, 0.0159813273910201, -0.033739462051023, 
    -0.00115459832436304, 0.0169207077575786, -0.00252612142439101, 
    0.0133094452453415, 0.00874908927566054, 0.00156455350865237, 
    0.00935258615825063, 0.00210095145298173, -0.00669794868412765, 
    0.0189215912698213, -0.00702817435321279, 0.00171232918551212, 
    0.00826014695620181, 0.00769553315353733, 0.00748064914645585, 
    -0.00351536096517346, 0.00896667197876688, 0.00239843339403389, 
    0.00460021391112875, 0.00876155976649162, 0.0124992436782625, 
    0.0106821380787201, -0.0180185055026785, 0.0163219842019382, 
    0.0181032895656239, -0.00942662125770344, 0.00430541589352629, 
    0.0233840751896519, -0.0112301415394915, 0.000507099402346611, 
    0.0056122358569386, -0.0093353018181288, 0.0101169263563117, 
    0.00645370897866204, -0.0119826580096527, 0.00289795984104302, 
    -0.00118964994019422, -0.00101162425117707, 0.00108611264251124, 
    0.0112418638169585, 0.0123434512360125, -0.00799426509711854
    ), SMB = c(0.00577986123704642, -0.00654011695984795, 0.0042588988477663, 
    -0.00577331652338534, -0.0128639051842341, -0.00282361989948447, 
    0.00926942672948123, -0.00159407144589641, -0.0234783005655727, 
    -0.00712297032430234, -0.0103213035279293, -0.00274604330460397, 
    -0.00466656929061131, -0.016816204260033, 8.58868959707285e-05, 
    -0.00799362290455943, 0.0038569537689772, -0.00677190397492088, 
    -0.00325934114735501, -0.0131595260940676, -0.0138924648790215, 
    0.0047656486529241, -0.00882280401870713, 0.00220287755331112, 
    -0.00790663911810646, 0.0128617254989806, -0.00624980745789196, 
    -0.0136368562338606, 0.0630771668546433, 0.0107550772971999, 
    0.00306313865369983, -0.00396381765801874, 0.0103787458202975, 
    -0.00877208964029707, 0.010554989886919, -0.00653487522327196, 
    -0.000389941615042667, 0.00227263868503461, -0.00848834855427348, 
    0.00943392498685034, -0.00557964548727661, 0.0124905605143232, 
    -0.00503318580725495, 0.00666531888024076, -0.0091831606237863, 
    -0.0141424474419593, -0.00906710036216694, 0.00760686358551667, 
    -0.00124867551633826, -0.0181691134987367), HML = c(-0.0400042937351153, 
    -0.0066708890999078, -0.00419892195763534, -0.0126775428108015, 
    -0.00907053024252952, 0.00176516902952155, -0.0140367618275742, 
    0.0270935738643608, 0.03025856502234, -0.0527335412243866, 
    -0.00265341704033851, 0.00475360385405994, 0.00613501648347071, 
    -0.00942339106863356, -0.017331328652346, 0.0102991439232348, 
    -0.00463866874691798, -0.00331670280829294, 0.0229807160745823, 
    -0.00680235096559611, 0.00552054376258217, 0.00109237331414049, 
    0.00261458884438971, 0.0167873311409555, -0.0116522606180712, 
    0.0145650942717742, -0.00830491968957432, -0.039973484903717, 
    -0.0367393701558186, 0.00697739820072437, 0.00884361674558607, 
    -0.032840145392728, 0.0188258170277682, -0.0080056184346814, 
    -0.000458489075829557, -0.0163708246599241, -0.0124225215058817, 
    NA, NA, -0.00888163441824433, 0.00267831319710646, -0.00496799083371276, 
    -0.00919771554021466, -0.00460054257751681, -0.01621692091088, 
    0.00814398108360904, -0.0103096795565, 0.00892735825198374, 
    0.0227557744740985, -0.00662193818332601), LIQ = c(-0.022369198083528, 
    0.0109845718520624, 0.0126788650487981, -0.00390201311323077, 
    0.00218050955131144, -0.0075959006271329, -0.00472483077475601, 
    0.00202996721820105, -0.0250449822597611, -0.00240069235579592, 
    0.00549835828400511, 0.00516517901008896, 0.00916860958085313, 
    0.0106929351484122, -0.0051815662059857, 0.000696733033235412, 
    -0.000478810098465092, -0.000147859788642631, -0.00926146895254349, 
    -0.00231258856162509, 0.00809611952583837, -0.00342299562292894, 
    0.00920161170178944, 0.00409966031023438, -0.00224480953984, 
    0.00817492288048398, 0.00299702126025813, -0.0039256704923854, 
    0.0783583024052581, -0.0119548733328832, 0.0226106399034113, 
    -0.0144970365164012, -0.00704842269310637, -0.00328544233296126, 
    -0.00152294642033654, -0.0012896602274351, 0.000839099896853023, 
    0.00760407607039239, 0.0283869119462006, 0.0148955895293236, 
    -0.00684754090040982, 0.012572323327271, -0.00645029371019245, 
    -0.000893370044570502, -0.00404915711882918, -0.00304640620093957, 
    0.00243945219102138, -0.00447910768154185, -0.0056372505556088, 
    0.00615880353476153), MOM = c(0.016500139365733, -0.00659043125965345, 
    -0.0105040752034117, -0.0129415244955013, 0.0154902420604264, 
    0.00262134695016149, 0.00682039997727063, -0.00274824040086975, 
    0.00445497119085701, -0.0200715167414251, -0.0172889092121903, 
    -0.0183097186084778, -0.00761068348240157, -0.019018744890486, 
    -0.00025262293205146, -0.0344974648260728, -0.0152223555564475, 
    -0.0020841576187069, -0.00183501446133657, -0.011794501394087, 
    -0.0229041856915202, 0.00796636153169424, -0.00229185373026946, 
    0.0251957167931911, -0.00629001005823519, 0.0181198183060087, 
    -0.0184232757504815, 0.049462958278229, 0.0148696918674201, 
    0.0149036102244975, 0.0071220259227979, -0.00164412962271088, 
    0.00315885138916578, -0.00466651772109416, 0.0296688259387658, 
    -0.00698475717864006, 0.00506839151556176, 0.0287125717104718, 
    0.0199037970427923, -0.00843964401884836, -0.00650954814458908, 
    0.00808833264229265, -0.00954095971123521, 0.000485354797368999, 
    0.0010823910051565, -0.0107780560665635, -0.00399074270905228, 
    0.0109014023267533, -0.00105720807106899, -0.00889838999687957
    ), Month = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
    11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4
    ), Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
    2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
    2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 
    2004, 2004), `Rf(1m)` = c("0.00528", "0.00525", "0.00548", 
    "0.00558", "0.00586", "0.00604", "0.00613", "0.00619", "0.00627", 
    "0.00613", "0.00608", "0.00613", "0.00632", "0.00601", "0.00614", 
    "0.00599", "0.00593", "0.00598", "0.00587", "0.00587", "0.00588", 
    "0.00548", "0.00555", "0.00554", "0.00558", "0.00560", "0.00558", 
    "0.00586", "0.00600", "0.00594", "0.00595", "0.00594", "0.00602", 
    "0.00551", "0.00508", "0.00474", "0.00473", "0.00435", "0.00423", 
    "0.00348", "0.00306", "0.00259", "0.00234", "0.00237", "0.00242", 
    "0.00207", "0.00183", "0.00163", "0.00162", "0.00163")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Rolling regression or just regression? You do know that your data suffers heavily from survivalship bias? You don't have the mutual funds that were terminated and who might have had better (or worse) alpha during the periods that they existed.

Comment: Anyhow, you might want to look in the the fable package. Here is the [whole book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) by Rob Hyndman. Required reading for forecasting.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time answering my question! The data above is just a random extraction used as an illustration and the data in whole do not suffer from survivalship bias as far as we can see. There are several funds that have been terminated that is taken into the study, and not 100+ funds all surving from start until today. We were hoping to get som tips on some codes that can be recommended in solving a regression on this size.

Comment: It is more a question for https://quant.stackexchange.com/ as there is no code yet. In R you have the package PerformanceAnalitics where jensen's index is calculated (amongst others).

Comment: Okei. I will follow up on your response. Thank you for replying.

Comment: We can't tell for sure what the problem is in reading the data in without the actual data and code but if it is a problem with nulls note the existence of the skipNul = TRUE argument when using read.zoo.